# Can callback show improved solutions with basinhopping without declaring a global variable?

Tags: python, scipy

I am using [basinhopping](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.basinhopping.html) from scipy and I would to see the progress that the optimizer is making. Currently I do:

```
def show_bh(a, b, c):
    global MIN
    if b < MIN:
        print([round(x, 2) for x in a], b)
        MIN = b
print("Optimizing using basinhopping")

MIN = 10
res = basinhopping(distance, x0 = points, niter=1000,
                   minimizer_kwargs={"bounds": bounds, "constraints": cons, "method": "SLSQP"},
                  callback=show_bh)
```

But this is horrible because of the global variable MIN. Is there a more elegant way to show progress?

Comment: I haven't fiddled with these callbacks, but it certainly is possible that you will have to use a global.  `basinhopping` should be clear as to what values it passes to the callback.  It you need to access something else, or "return" come value, you have to accept globals.  That feature isn't bad in-and-of-itself; it's its misuse that's bad.

Comment: Since `show_bh` needs to change `MIN`, it might make sense to create a class, with `MIN` as an attribute (maybe use a lowercase name, but not `min` since that's a builtin), and `show_bh` as a method.

Comment: I'd suggest editing the subject line so it's more focused on the callback.  General "improve" questions often get closed as too broad or otherwise belonging elsewhere, like code review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a nice solution by @JonSG. There's a variation on this that allows you to keep track of the minimisation:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import basinhopping, rosen

def build_show_bh(MIN=None):
    if MIN is None:
        MIN = [np.inf]

    def fn(xx, f, accept):
        if f < MIN[-1]:
            print([round(x, 2) for x in xx], f)
            MIN.append(f)
    return fn

c = build_show_bh()
print("Optimizing using basinhopping")
res = basinhopping(
    rosen, [10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
    callback=c
)

# or
progress_f = [np.inf]
c = build_show_bh(progress_f)
print("Optimizing using basinhopping")
res = basinhopping(
    rosen, [10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
    niter=1000,
    callback=c
)
print(f"external way of keeping track of MINF: {progress_f}")
```

You can obviously amend this to keep track of all kinds of things.

Answer (score 1):

How about building a closure?  `MIN` would still be outside the context of the function call, but not `global`.  Maybe something like:

```py
def build_show_bh(MIN):
    def fn(a, b, c):
        nonlocal MIN
        if b < MIN:
            print([round(x, 2) for x in a], b)
            MIN = b
    return fn

print("Optimizing using basinhopping")
res = basinhopping(
    distance,
    x0=points,
    niter=1000,
    minimizer_kwargs={"bounds": bounds, "constraints": cons, "method": "SLSQP"},
    callback=build_show_bh(10)
)
```